# Angular2 model-driven form validator pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm trying to make a form valid only if it matches a certain pattern.

It must match:

```
123456789
123-456-789
123 458 789
```

Here is my pattern:

```
^(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3})|(\d{3} \d{3} \d{3})|(\d{9})$
```

First, fun fact, to be able to use it on Validator, it seems i've to escape every slash in it.

```
Validators.pattern('^(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3})|(\\d{3} \\d{3} \\d{3})|(\\d{9})$')
```

And my problem is it doesn't restrict the total string size number.

For example, it matches 1234567890000, i would like it to stop at 123456789 and any additional character would trigger the false state.

I tried these variants:

```
Validators.pattern('^(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3})|(\\d{3} \\d{3} \\d{3})|(\\d{9})$')
Validators.pattern('(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3})|(\\d{3} \\d{3} \\d{3})|(\\d{9})')
```

Another fun fact, if I set it to:

```
Validators.pattern('\\d{9}')
```

or

```
Validators.pattern('^\\d{9}$')
```

Then i can only set exactly 9 characters.

I'm sure it's a regex error, but i don't understand if Angular2 requires to give him `^` and `$` symbols to delimit the string to be evaluated.

Comment: Try `'(?:\\d{3}([- ])\\d{3}\\1\\d{3}|\\d{9})'`. The expression in the `Validators.pattern` is anchored by default, no need to add `^` and `$`.

Comment: On your Plunkr, try typing `123-456-7891111` in the field. It pass the validation but the intended behavior is that the validator trigger an error after 123-456-789. My rule must be: 9 digits, separated/or not, with `-` or space.

Comment: But my suggestion above works, right? See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pGsb23WQmamwChLEWRht?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use double backslashes because the pattern is passed to the regex engine as a string literal, and regex escaping requires literal backslashes with `\d`, `\w`, etc.

From what I see from my testing, angular adds `^` and `$` anchors around the pattern *without grouping* it.

That means, when you have alternation groups, *wrap them with a grouping construct* so that the anchors could be applied to all the alternatives.

Your `^(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3})|(\\d{3} \\d{3} \\d{3})|(\\d{9})$` and other attemped patterns contain unwrapped alternatives, so `^` only applies to `(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3})` and `$` only applies to `(\\d{9})`.

Use

```
'(?:\\d{3}([- ])\\d{3}\\1\\d{3}|\\d{9})'
```

Inside the validator code, it will appear as `^(?:\\d{3}([- ])\\d{3}\\1\\d{3}|\\d{9})$`, and will work like [in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/vxyi9l/1).

**Details**: the pattern will match 2 alternatives:

- `\\d{3}([- ])\\d{3}\\1\\d{3}` - 3 digits, `-` or space (captured into Group 1), then 3 digits, then the same separator as in Group 1, and then 3 digits
- `|` - or
- `\\d{9}` - 9 digits

Since the `^` and `$` are added by angular, the patterns will require full string match.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, it now works as expected. I didn't know about the grouping construct operator.

Comment: I consider it a bug, the angular dev team should have implemented the same behavior as in HTML5 pattern: wrap the pattern with `^(?:` and `)$`. It creates an additional layer to the expression anchoring it in a way that won't ruin the user's logic.

Comment: If i understood properly, now my regex validating a kind of date format (YYYYMMDD) could be entered as `(?:\\d{4}([-. ])\\d{2}\\1\\d{2}|\\d{8})`

Comment: Yes, the backslashes before `d` must be doubled and the whole pattern should be wrapped within a non-capturing group. You can even add `^` and `$` at the end, they will do no harm.

Answer (score -1):

Setting a Validator.maxLength will not allow the user to type past the given length of chars.

```
new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(9)
```

Comment: I can't use it because on my regex, the user must be able to separate the 9 digits with - or spaces, by groups of free. It's for a canadian SIN, with global form 123-456-789. But sometimes people don't use dash, but spaces or nothing as separators.